# Memory usage in Firefox when rapidly replacing image src

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to implement an animated PNG using Javascript by replacing an image's src every 100 ms. It displays fine, but I've found that it gradually consumes more and more memory when left to run on Firefox.

This is the loop I use for playing the animation, though I don't think there's anything spectacular about it -

```
self.next = function() {
    if(self.doPlay == true) {
        self.currentFrame++;
        if(self.currentFrame >= self.numFrames) {
            self.currentFrame = 0;
            self.doPlay = self.doLoop;
        }
    }
    if(self.doPlay == true) {
        image.src = self.frames[self.currentFrame].src;
        setTimeout( self.next, self.frameDelays[self.currentFrame]);
    }
}
```

(where frames is an array of preloaded Image objects)

If I comment out the change in src, memory usage is fine. Otherwise, memory usage climbs indefinitely  until the browser eventually crashes.

I've tried removing and replacing the image from the DOM instead of changing the src (both in vanilla and with jQuery), but it didn't seem to help.

Anyone know a better way?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Are you saying the problem is in Firefox only, i.e., that it works in other browsers?

Comment: It seems to work fine on Chrome, but I haven't tried on any other major browsers as of yet.

Comment: This is a ridiculously bad idea.

Comment: @Walkerneo If you have time, could you possibly elaborate? If not, thanks for your time anyway =)

Comment: That's very odd behavior.  There shouldn't be any persistent memory growth going on here.  I assume you can reproduce this in safe mode or a clean profile (i.e. with all extensions disabled)?  If so, can you possibly post a link to a complete page showing the problem so I can debug it a bit?  Once I understand why you're seeing what you're seeing I can probably recommend a way to work around it...

Answer (score 2):

You ever thought about using an image only and change the scroll in the background?
it's really fast and recommended

look this

http://willian.nerdti.com.br/botaoImagem.html

Comment: I've seen this done before, not sure why it didn't occur to me! Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to this question, but rather another comment (that I can't leave, because my StackOverflow reputation is currently not at 50).  Anyway, I noticed that someone above (in the comments section) said that this was a ridiculously bad idea.  He may be right, for this particular scenario, but this memory leak has raised it's head in our application, in a completley unanticipated way (and has caused us to abandon FireFox all-together).

Basically, our application has a left-hand navigation bar that contains small avatars of various people in our organization.  This left-hand navigation bar can be filtered, sorted, updated, etc.  This bar can (at times) contain several hundred images and with each shuffle of this bar, FireFox looses 500K to 1MB a clip, whereas IE9/10, Chrome and Safari don't loose a thing.

So, until this bug is fixed, FireFox (for our internal application) is no longer a viable option.